# Create a dimensional table from an event data stream

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, gaps-and-islands, dimensional-modeling

Possibly a bit of an odd question given that dimensional tables mostly get created by wizards in RDBMSs as far as I have seen. But I want to see if I can create a dimensional table with a SQL query from a data table that is an event stream.

For example, let's say I have a table `bodyshops` that contains an event stream that periodically outputs bodyshops' data:

| event_id | bodyshop_name | time | phone_number | address |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Body1 | 2022-10-05 11:30 | 12345 | abc |
| 2 | Body1 | 2022-10-05 11:35 | 56789 | abc |
| 3 | Body2 | 2022-10-05 11:36 | 34563 | def |

I would like to generate a table that goes something like:

| bodyshop_name | phone_number | address | start_time | end_time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Body1 | 12345 | abc | 2022-10-05 11:30 | 2022-10-05 11:35 |
| Body1 | 56789 | abc | 2022-10-05 11:35 | Null |
| Body2 | 34563 | def | 2022-10-05 11:36 | Null |

What would be the SQL statement to generate this? if it matters, it's for a columnar store (I know it's not the ideal database for these type of tables, but need to have one of those in there).

Comment: Please tag your DBMS

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to achieve. For example, why are there two rows for "Body1" in the output and why has the time from one of the input rows been used as the end time for the other? Why isn't there just one "Body1" row in the output? You need to help us out and explain what you're trying to do.